# Hide p tag with text until is need it

Tags: reactjs

I have a search bar that displays a

tag with some text saying " No files match your search. I need to hide the p-tag it should have a css class that has "display: none" until there is text in it. I'm trying to accomplish this with a little js.

Here is my code in my react app:

```
let errorMessage = ''
    if (!this.state.files.length && !this.state.folders.length) {
      errorMessage = "You don't have any files in storage yet."
    } else if (this.props.searchValue && !filesToDisplay.length) {
      errorMessage = 'No files match your search.'
    }

    <p className='search-error'>{errorMessage}</p>
```

and my css:

```
.search-error {
  text-align: center;
  color: $primary-text-color;
  padding: 0 1em;
  font-size: 2em;
  word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can conditionally render the `search-error` only if the `searchValue` prop has something in it:

```
return (
  (other JSX here)
  {
    this.props.searchValue
      ? <p className='search-error'>{errorMessage}</p>
      : null
  }
);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can render the p tag according to errorMessage value

```
{
  errorMessage &&  <p className='search-error'>{errorMessage}</p>
}
```